# Using intersperse and show

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get this code:

```
intersperse ',' $ show 123
```

integrated into this function:

```
printListTuples listTuple = unlines [ ys ++ " " ++ unwords (map show x) | (x, ys) <- listTuple ]
```

where x can be equal to 123 for this example.

Therefore the code should output a string with numbers like this:
"1,2,3"

rather than just "1 2 3" like this code currently does.

I keep getting errors trying to "map" "intersperse" and "show" to x in the function. Any advice?

EDIT:

For example, I tried using

```
printListTuples listTuple = unlines [ ys ++ " " ++  unwords (map intersperse ',' $ show x) | (x, ys) <- listTuple ]
```

but this returns an error:

```
    Couldn't match expected type ‘String -> [String]’
                with actual type ‘[[a0] -> [a0]]’
    The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
    but its type ‘[[a0] -> [a0]]’ has none
    In the first argument of ‘unwords’, namely
      ‘(map intersperse ',' $ show x)’
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
      ‘unwords (map intersperse ',' $ show x)’

    Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’ with actual type ‘Char’
    In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘','’
    In the expression: map intersperse ','
    In the first argument of ‘unwords’, namely
      ‘(map intersperse ',' $ show x)’
```

which I do not know enough about to fix.

Comment: "I keep getting errors" -- *Which* errors? (Compiler errors are not gibberish; you should try to understand them.)

Comment: And, whether you understand them or not, you should include them in your question.

Comment: @duplode, unfortunately, GHC type errors can be rather intimidating, especially to new users. They may talk about strange vocabulary like ambiguous type variables, skolems, etc. GHC's parse errors, on the other hand, tend to be rather uninformative.

Comment: I agree, I updated the post with an error I got when compiling a implementation of intersperse and show

Comment: @dfeuer Indeed. That makes it even more important to include the errors, so that answers can help making sense of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's have a look at first error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘String -> [String]’
            with actual type ‘[[a0] -> [a0]]’
The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
but its type ‘[[a0] -> [a0]]’ has none
In the first argument of ‘unwords’, namely
  ‘(map intersperse ',' $ show x)’
```

"The first argument of `($)` takes one argument" -- that means it should be a function, as its type shows:

```
GHCi> :t ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

`map intersperse ','`, however, is not a function. As you are passing two arguments to `map`, it would be a list...

```
GHCi> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

... however, `map intersperse ','` is ill-typed: `','` is not a list, so you cannot use `map` to map a function over it (that is what the other error says). The root of the issue is that you don't need `map` to apply `intersperse ','` to a `String`:

```
GHCi> :t intersperse ','
intersperse ',' :: [Char] -> [Char]
```

That will fix the two errors... and introduce another:

```
GHCi> let printListTuples listTuple = unlines [ ys ++ " " ++  unwords (intersperse ',' $ show x) | (x, ys) <- listTuple ]

<interactive>:33:66:
    Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: [String]
      Actual type: [Char]
    In the first argument of ‘unwords’, namely
      ‘(intersperse ',' $ show x)’
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
      ‘unwords (intersperse ',' $ show x)’
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
      ‘" " ++ unwords (intersperse ',' $ show x)’
```

Now `unwords` wants a list of `String`s, but we are giving it `intersperse ',' $ show x`, which is a list of `Char`s (that is, a `String`). That directs our attention to the fact that we do not need `unwords` anymore: it was only used to put a space between the numbers, but now we want to put a comma instead of a space, and we are already doing that with `intersperse`. So all we have to do is removing it:

```
GHCi> let printListTuples listTuple = unlines [ ys ++ " " ++  (intersperse ',' $ show x) | (x, ys) <- listTuple ]
```

*Et voilà*:

```
GHCi> printListTuples [(123, "foo"), (456, "bar")]
"foo 1,2,3\nbar 4,5,6\n"
```

From here, you should decompose your function into smaller parts, as user5402 suggests in their answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try to avoid writing complex expressions. You can use `let` and `where` clauses to create intermediate definitions. Then build up your final expression from smaller, tested expressions.

For instance, you have identified a useful expression:

```
intersperse ',' $ show x
```

So create a definition which encapsulates this:

```
commify x = intersperse ',' (show x)
```

And then you can ask ghci for its signature:

```
ghci> :t commify
commify :: Show a => a -> String
```

Next, tackle the problem of printing just a single tuple:

```
printTuple (x,ys) = ys ++ " " ++ ...
```

Once you have that working, your `printListTuple` function is just:

```
printListTuple listTuples
   = unlines [ printTuple (x,ys) | (x,ys) <- listTuples ]
```

which is easy to read and understand.

Comment: I suspect `intersperse ',' . show` is actually not what the OP wants, but you couldn't have guessed that from the question.

Comment: I think they actually want `intercalate "," . map show`